# Simple object oriented design for an Temperature class

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, unit-conversion

> 1. Design a temperature class for nurses to store patient temperature and the method of taking the temperature.
> 2. How would you handle different units of temperature? Write a function to determine if a patient has a fever.

My approach

```
class Temperature
    attr_accessor :temp, :method

    def initialize(temp,method)
        @temp = temp
        @method =method
    end

end

class Celsius < Temperature

    TEMP = 37

    def has_fever
        if temp > TEMP
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

end

class Fahrenheit < Temperature

    TEMP =98.6

        def has_fever
            if temp > TEMP
                true
            else
                false
            end
        end
end
```

I know there is a code duplication in Celsius and Fahrenheit class. I tried declaring `has_fever` method in `Temperature` class but it didn't work. It says `"uninitialized constant Temperature::TEMP"`.

Is there something to improve this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Make the base class meaningful

Right now you've declared `Temperature` as a base class, but all it really does is set up your two variables.  One way to utilize it more would be to assign a unit of some sort to the class (I've chosen Kelvin, but it could have been anything).

In my version, `Temperature` stores everything as Kelvin.  Any class that inherits from it only has to know how to convert back and forth to Kelvin (So Celsius<->Kelvin and Fahrenheit<->Kelvin).  Later, if I wanted to add operators to add/subtract/compare temperatures, since the base units are all kelvin, everything is easy.

You'll also notice that I've moved `has_temp?` to the base class and the threshold temperature is in Kelvin.  This gives all sub-classes the functionality without having to know anything about where the theshold is, and likewise the base class will always work without needing to know the details of a particular unit of measure.

Finally, while I've used Kelvin as the unit for `Temperature`, the base class could have just as easily been called `Kelvin`.

```
class Temperature
  attr_accessor :temp, :method

  FEVER_THRESHOLD = 310.15  # 98.6F to K

  def initialize(temp, method)
    @temp = temp
    @method =method
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@temp} K"
  end

  def has_fever?
    @temp > FEVER_THRESHOLD
  end
end


class Celsius < Temperature
  def self.to_k(value)
    value + 273.15
  end

  def self.from_k(value)
    value - 273.15
  end

  def initialize(temp, method)
    super(Celsius.to_k(temp), method)
  end

  def to_s
    "%0.2f C" % [Celsius.from_k(@temp)]
  end  
end


class Fahrenheit < Temperature
  def self.to_k(value)
    (value + 459.67) * (5.0/9.0)
  end

  def self.from_k(value)
    (value * 9.0/5.0) - 459.67
  end

  def initialize(temp, method)
    super(Fahrenheit.to_k(temp), method)
  end

  def to_s
    "%0.2f F" % [Fahrenheit.from_k(@temp)]
  end  
end

#test Celsius
temp = Celsius.new(39, nil)
puts temp.to_s         # 39.0 C
puts temp.has_fever?   # true

#test Fahrenheit
temp = Fahrenheit.new(97.9, nil)
puts temp.to_s         # 97.90 F
puts temp.has_fever?   # false
```

On a personal note, I wouldn't necessarily use inheritance as my go-to solution for *this* problem without a lot more knowledge and thought about the use-cases; I only followed your initial design.  Temperatures themselves are fairly trivial, but perhaps for a more complicated scenario this implementation would have advantages.